# Using syscall 13 in MIPS-Assembler

Tags: assembly, mips, system-calls, qtspim

I'm studying computer since and my task at the moment is, to learn how to program in MIPS assembler, using qtSPIM.

The task, which I'm working with at the moment is, writing a program as a routine to load a picture (PGM 5, binary) from my hard drive into an array. At the beginnig of the piture there is also a header, which contains width, length, color depth and amount of collors.

As far as I found out, I have to use syscall 14 to do this. The arguments of this function are "$a0 = file descriptor, $a1 = buffer, $a2 = length". But I unfortunately didn't find any information about the right Syntax of a program using this function to read a picture with a certain size (64x64 pixel).

I would be very glad an thankful, if anyone could help me solving this task.

Thanks in advance,

Mic

Comment: What's the question? What have you tried and what is your code so far?

Comment: MY code, sofar, looks like this:

#
# load_img
#

.data

buffer:  .space 4096


.text

main:  la   $a0, buffer # load bite space into buffer
   li   $a1, 4096 # allot the bite space for string
   move  $to, $a0 # save String to $t0

   li  $v0, 13
   syscall


    jr $ra

Comment: What I cannot understand is, how to tell the programm the adress of the file it has to read. As I already said, this file is on my hard drive...

Comment: Edit it into the question itself with proper formatting. Also there's no clear question in the... well, question.

Comment: While I know nothing about your system or anything, according to you the syscall takes a buffer, so you would likely need to load the file into the memory somehow.

Answer (score 1):

`syscall 14` needs: "$a0 = file descriptor, $a1 = buffer, $a2 = length"

To get file descriptor of your file, you will have to open it for reading, using [`syscall 13`](https://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/Help/SyscallHelp.html) "$a0 = address of null-terminated string containing filename $a1 = flags $a2 = mode"

> Service 13 - MARS implements three flag values: 0 for read-only, 1 for write-only with create, and 9 for write-only with create and append. It ignores mode. The returned file descriptor will be negative if the operation failed. The underlying file I/O implementation uses java.io.FileInputStream.read() to read and java.io.FileOutputStream.write() to write. MARS maintains file descriptors internally and allocates them starting with 3. File descriptors 0, 1 and 2 are always open for: reading from standard input, writing to standard output, and writing to standard error, respectively (new in release 4.3).

There's also example in that documentation.

There's no service to get file information (like length), so you will have to read the file either as stream and process it meanwhile, or allocate big enough buffer to read all your pgm files in one go. 64x64 is 4096 bytes (if 8 bit greyscale is used), so that buffer of yours will be not enough, pgm file has also header.

syscall 16 is close file (don't forget to call it after reading).

> But I unfortunately didn't find any information about the right Syntax of a program using this function to read a picture with a certain size (64x64 pixel).

Uh... you simply read like first 2000 bytes into buffer (that should cover any header), then you parse those data, extracting values for width/heigh/maxcolor, and detecting start of pixel data.

Then you proceed the rest of the 2000 bytes as pixel data (you can use syscall 9 to allocate required memory for pixel data dynamically, or just create another `pixels: .space 4096` buffer if you know for sure the input is 64x64 8bit greyscale) copying them into final pixel buffer, and then you read again as many bytes as you have available in the read-file buffer, and copy further pixels... until width x height pixels were read.

Then close the file.

Sounds very simple to me, can't see where is your problem. Maybe show few examples, what did you come with, to show what is problematic for you, but whole assembly is like moving numbers here and there, not much else to do, so as long as you can formulate all your tasks as algorithm of moving numbers here and there, you are fine.